# Javascript SDK: Check if a user liked a facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I want to check if a user has liked a page or not and based on it display the contents of the website!
Following is the code using FQL. Is there any way for the same using Javascript SDK?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.session) {
          var user_id = response.session.uid;
          var page_id = "1553725881514063"; //Swoopshows page id
          var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = "+page_id+"and uid="+user_id;
          var the_query = FB.Data.query(fql_query);

          the_query.wait(function(rows) {

              if (rows.length == 1 && rows[0].uid == user_id) {
                  alert("Liked");

                  //here you could also do some ajax and get the content for a "liker" instead of simply showing a hidden div in the page.

              } else {
                  alert("not liked");
                  //and here you could get the content for a non liker in ajax...
              }
          });


      } else {
        // user is not logged in
        alert("Please Login to continue");
      }
    });
});
```

Also, in my SDK initiation, i have mentioned the version to be 2.0. Still this doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't work anymore, because Facebook is discouraging "Like-gating" content.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_1_90_day_deprecations

> The 'liked' property will no longer be returned in the 'signed_request' object for Page Tab apps created after today. From November 5, 2014 onwards, the 'liked' property will always return 'true' regardless of whether or not the person has liked the page.

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1#reference-user_likes

As you'd need the `user_likes` permission to determine whether a user has likes the page, and thereby need an app review, you'll very likely not be able to get the permission approved:

> Not allowed: Gate access to your app, or some content within your app based on whether or not someone has liked a page.

Comment: Yeah, app review was rejected stating the very same reason. Thanks for answer anyways. :)